# How to display readme.md file on profile in Github?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I have created a `README.md` file in my `username.github.io` repository but it doesn't appear on my profile page:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Profile READMEs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme) must be [located in a public repository named after your GitHub user name](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme#prerequisites). This is different from your GitHub Pages User site.

Assuming your GitHub username is `username`:

- Your GitHub Pages User Site should be in a repository named `username.github.io`. You already have one of these.
- The repository for your profile `README.md` should *just* be named `username`. Create a new repository with that name and add your `README.md` there.

Comment: I have created a repository using the wrong name and renamed it to use the same name as my Github username and not worked. If you have done the same try to delete it and create another repository using the correct name.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to create a *new repository* with the name as your username (ProgrammerGaurav) and create a README.md in that repository.

Answer (score 2):

we can create via visual studio editor. create a file with name README.md and in this file create your page profile page. And push to github via version control

Answer (score 2):

Create a repo that is named the same as your username. let's assume your username is `ProgrammerGaurav`. so you need to create a new repository with the name ProgrammerGaurav.

> Note: at the time of this writing, in order to access the profile
> README feature, the letter-casing must match your GitHub username and
> your GitHub repository visibility should be in public.

Create a README inside that repo and edit it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The repository of `username.github.io` should be `https://github.com/username/username.github.io`
It is a github page, see [types-of-github-pages-sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)

> To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<username>.github.io`.

---

The repository of `profile with README.md` should be `https://github.com/username/username`

See [managing-your-profile-readme](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme)

It is your profile information.

> You've created a repository with a name that matches your GitHub username.
> The repository is public.
> The repository contains a file named README.md in its root.
> The README.md file contains any content.

And you need to click the `Share to profile` button after creating the repository to show the content to your profile.

---

So, They are different repositories.

See also [awesome-github-profile-readme](https://github.com/abhisheknaiidu/awesome-github-profile-readme),
[github-readme-stats](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats)

Answer (score 0):

You get a green pop-up window on the right of your repository where README.md is stored. Click add to profile to make it work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -3):

create a repository with your username. your profile readme file will be created and then you can edit it as you

Comment: There are already _six existing answers_, including an accepted answer with ten upvotes. This answer just seems to repeat what four of them already say, with less detail. Please don't repeat answers. See [answer].